# Rename all column names with a suffix except listed column name using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm hoping this is a simple question.  How do I rename all of the column header names in a data set with the suffix "_2017" except the first 2 column headers which are: "Name", and "State"?  I'd like to use dplyr to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `rename_at` and exclude columns using `vars` helper method:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c('a', 'b'), State = c('c', 'd'), col1 = 1:2, col2 = 3:4)
df
#  Name State col1 col2
#1    a     c    1    3
#2    b     d    2    4
```

*Exclude with hard coded names:*

```
df %>% rename_at(vars(-Name, -State), ~ paste0(., '_2017'))
#  Name State col1_2017 col2_2017
#1    a     c         1         3
#2    b     d         2         4
```

*Exclude by column positions:*

```
df %>% rename_at(vars(-(1:2)), ~ paste0(., '_2017'))
#  Name State col1_2017 col2_2017
#1    a     c         1         3
#2    b     d         2         4
```

*Exclude by column names stored in a variable:*

```
to_exclude = c('Name', 'State')
df %>% rename_at(vars(-one_of(to_exclude)), ~ paste0(., '_2017'))
#  Name State col1_2017 col2_2017
#1    a     c         1         3
#2    b     d         2         4
```

Answer (score 10):

`rename_if()`, `rename_at()`, and `rename_all()` have been superseded by `rename_with()`.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c('a', 'b'), State = c('c', 'd'), 
                 col1 = 1:2, col2 = 3:4)

# De-select by location
df %>% rename_with(~paste0(., "_2017"), -c(1:2))

#>   Name State col1_2017 col2_2017
#> 1    a     c         1         3
#> 2    b     d         2         4


# De-select by name 
df %>% rename_with(~paste0(., "_2017"), -c("Name", "State"))

#>   Name State col1_2017 col2_2017
#> 1    a     c         1         3
#> 2    b     d         2         4


# De-select using another variable that holds names
deselect_names <- c("Name", "State")
df %>% rename_with(~paste0(., "_2017"), -!!deselect_names)

#>   Name State col1_2017 col2_2017
#> 1    a     c         1         3
#> 2    b     d         2         4
```